# Noise in sound after using RDP

Tags: windows-7, audio, remote-desktop

I don't know why but after using my `Office PC` remotely (RDP) from any place, its sound is being "bugged": a skratchy noise appears at some interval ~ 20-40 seconds.

Rebooting the PC helps, but I'd like another solution.

### Question:

Is there a solution or some clues upon that? (Note this bug appears ONLY after RDP connection)

#### PC Characteristics:

- **OS:**           Windows 7 X64 Ultimate
- **Sound Driver:** Realtek HD v6.0.1.6657
- **MB:**           Asus P8Z77-V LK

Answer (score 0):

try this:

1. Click on ‘Start’ and type ‘remote desktop connections’ and Enter.
2. In the ‘remote desktop connections’ click on ‘Options’ and select ‘Local Resource’ tab.
3. Click on ‘Settings’ under Remote audio.
4. Select ‘Play on this computer’.
5. Click ‘OK’.

Comment: I'll perform these operations ASAP. And add some feedback after. Meanwhile thanks for your answer.